# How do I dynamically define a method as private?

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming, access-specifier

This does not seem to work:

```
class Test
  private

  define_method :private_method do 
    "uh!"
  end
end

puts Test.new.private_method
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
Test.instance_eval { private :private_method }
```

Or, just run

```
private :private_method
```

from within the `Test` class.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that starting with Ruby 2.1, `define_method` respects `private`:

```
$ rvm 2.1.0
$ ruby /tmp/test.rb
/tmp/test.rb:10:in `<main>': private method `private_method' called for #<Test:0x00000102014598> (NoMethodError)
$ rvm 2.0
$ ruby /tmp/test.rb
uh!
```

(I realize this is an old question, but I happened across it via Google.)

Answer (score 7):

`Module#private` takes an optional argument for the method name:

```
class Test
 private :private_method
end
```

The above is of course equivalent to

```
Test.private :private_method # doesn't work
```

Except that `Module#private` is private, so you have to use reflection to circumvent the access restrictions:

```
Test.send :private, :private_method
```

No `eval` necessary.