# Is it possible to dynamically inspect the method visibility scope (private/public/protected)?

Tags: ruby

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23701074/5267234), in Ruby 2.1 or later, this code:

```
class SimpleTest
  private

  define_method :foo do 
    42
  end
end
```

will define `foo` as a private method of `SimpleTest` instances. (In Ruby 2.0 and earlier it won't be private.) However, I'm looking to do something a little less trivial. I would like to define a DSL that classes can extend, and would like the methods that the DSL defines internally to respect the private/protected visibility of the calling context. That may not be clear, so here's an example:

```
module Dsl
  def has_a(name)
    define_method name do
      42
    end
  end
end

class Test
  extend Dsl

  private

  has_a :thing
end
```

As written, that code will define a *public* `thing` method on `Test` instances. Instead, I would like `has_a` to be able to reflect on the method visibility where it was called (`private` in this case), and define `thing` under that same method visibility.

I'm not familiar with Ruby's C source code, but I took a quick look and found [this function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2f8a4d317f70f58e3008b2aa814e48a45c6427f6/vm_method.c#L1035) which seems like it might do what I want, but I don't think it's accessible from Ruby. (It seems to only be used [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2f8a4d317f70f58e3008b2aa814e48a45c6427f6/vm_method.c#L1080).) I also looked up the documentation for `define_method` (since the first example works as desired) [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) and it seems like the `noex` variable declared and set here:

```
int noex = NOEX_PUBLIC;
const NODE *cref = rb_vm_cref_in_context(mod, mod);

if (cref) {
    noex = (int)cref->nd_visi;
}
```

could be the value I want, but again I don't know how I would get that in Ruby, or even if it would be able to reflect back on the calling scope (in `Test`). Assuming I had the visibility, then I could simply call `private name` (or `protected name`) after the `define_method` call inside `has_a` if it wasn't called in a `public` context.

Thoughts? Is there any way to do this, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has a similar answer to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075865/5129208

It looks like the author of that made a custom module to get the behavior you're after.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that. I didn't see it when I searched before asking. It's an interesting solution, though I'd prefer not having to prepend something to `Module`.